# 7x4 grid displaying 1 button 28 times instead of 28 different buttons being displayed. Why?

Tags: python, tkinter-layout

I would like to display the 28 buttons below in a 7x4 self-resizing grid.  As it stands now, the equal button is being displayed 28 times.  I need all 28 different buttons to display in the 7x4 grid. I have all 28 different buttons configured with the row_index and col_index variables, but it's still not working. If you could help steer me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it.

...

```
enter code here
```

class Calculator(ttk.Frame)
def **init**(self):
root = Tk()
root.title("TK's Calculator")
root.geometry("700x500")

```
    Grid.rowconfigure(root, 0, weight=1)
    Grid.columnconfigure(root, 0, weight=1)

    root.resizable(True, True)
    
    frame1 = Frame(root, bg="#80c1ff", bd=5)
    frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

    for row_index in range(7):
        Grid.rowconfigure(frame1, row_index, weight=1)
        
    for col_index in range(4):
        Grid.columnconfigure(frame1, col_index, weight=1)
        
        buttonMC = Button(frame1, text="MC", height=3, width=5, command=MC)
        buttonMC.grid(row=row_index, column=col_index, sticky="nsew")
        buttonMC.configure(width=7, height=3, font=("Verdana", 10, "bold"), fg="Navy")

        MRButton = Button(frame1, text="MR", height=3, width=5, command=MR)
        MRButton.grid(row=row_index, column=col_index, sticky="nsew")
        MRButton.configure(width=7, height=3, font=("Verdana", 10, "bold"), fg="Navy")

        MPlusButton = Button(frame1, text="M+", height=3, width=5, command=MPlus)
        MPlusButton.grid(row=row_index, column=col_index, sticky="nsew")
        MPlusButton.configure(width=7, height=3, font=("Verdana", 10, "bold"), fg="Navy")

        percentButton = Button(frame1, text="%", height=3, width=5, command=percent)
        percentButton.grid(row=row_index, column=col_index, sticky="nsew")
        percentButton.configure(width=7, height=3, font=("Verdana", 10, "bold"), fg="Navy")

        buttonModulo = Button(frame1, text="Mod", height=3, width=5, command=modulo)
        buttonModulo.grid(row=row_index, column=col_index, sticky="nsew")
        buttonModulo.configure(width=7, height=3, font=("Verdana", 10, "bold"), fg="Navy")

        buttonSqRoot = Button(frame1, text="√(x)", height=3, width=5, command=squareRootOfx)
        buttonSqRoot.grid(row=row_index, column=col_index, sticky="nsew")
        buttonSqRoot.configure(width=7, height=3, font=("Verdana", 10, "bold"), fg="Navy")

        button2ndPower = Button(frame1, text="x²", height=3, width=5, command=powerOf2)
        button2ndPower.grid(row=row_index, column=col_index, sticky="nsew")
        button2ndPower.configure(width=7, height=3, font=("Verdana", 10, "bold"), fg="Navy")

        buttonOneOverX = Button(frame1, text="1/x", height=3, width=5, command=oneOverX)
        buttonOneOverX.grid(row=row_index, column=col_index, sticky="nsew")
        buttonOneOverX.configure(width=7, height=3, font=("Verdana", 10, "bold"), fg="Navy")

        buttonCE = Button(frame1, text="CE", height=3, width=5, command=clearEntry)
        buttonCE.grid(row=row_index, column=col_index, sticky="nsew")
        buttonCE.configure(width=7, height=3, font=("Verdana", 10, "bold"), fg="Navy")

        buttonClear = Button(frame1, text="C", height=3, width=5, command=clear)
        buttonClear.grid(row=row_index, column=col_index, sticky="nsew")
        buttonClear.configure(width=7, height=3, font=("Verdana", 10, "bold"), fg="Navy")

        buttonDelete = Button(frame1, text="del", height=3, width=5, command=delete)
        buttonDelete.grid(row=row_index, column=col_index, sticky="nsew")
        buttonDelete.configure(width=7, height=3, font=("Verdana", 10, "bold"), fg="Navy")

        buttonDivide = Button(frame1, text="/", height=3, width=5, command=divide)
        buttonDivide.grid(row=row_index, column=col_index, sticky="nsew")
        buttonDivide.configure(width=7, height=3, font=("Verdana", 10, "bold"), fg="Navy")

        button7 = Button(frame1, text="7", height=3, width=5, command=lambda: buttonClick(7))
        button7.grid(row=row_index, column=col_index, sticky="nsew")
        button7.configure(width=7, height=3, font=("Verdana", 10, "bold"), fg="Navy")

        button8 = Button(frame1, text="8", height=3, width=5, command=lambda: buttonClick(8))
        button8.grid(row=row_index, column=col_index, sticky="nsew")
        button8.configure(width=7, height=3, font=("Verdana", 10, "bold"), fg="Navy")

        button9 = Button(frame1, text="9", height=3, width=5, command=lambda: buttonClick(9))
        button9.grid(row=row_index, column=col_index, sticky="nsew")
        button9.configure(width=7, height=3, font=("Verdana", 10, "bold"), fg="Navy")
        

        buttonMultiply = Button(frame1, text="x", height=3, width=5, command=multiply)
        buttonMultiply.grid(row=row_index, column=col_index, sticky="nsew")
        buttonMultiply.configure(width=7, height=3, font=("Verdana", 10, "bold"), fg="Navy")

        button4 = Button(frame1, text="4", height=3, width=5, command=lambda: buttonClick(4))
        button4.grid(row=row_index, column=col_index, sticky="nsew")
        button4.configure(width=7, height=3, font=("Verdana", 10, "bold"), fg="Navy")

        button5 = Button(frame1, text="5", height=3, width=5, command=lambda: buttonClick(5))
        button5.grid(row=row_index, column=col_index, sticky="nsew")
        button5.configure(width=7, height=3, font=("Verdana", 10, "bold"), fg="Navy")

        button6 = Button(frame1, text="6", height=3, width=5, command=lambda: buttonClick(6))
        button6.grid(row=row_index, column=col_index, sticky="nsew")
        button6.configure(width=7, height=3, font=("Verdana", 10, "bold"), fg="Navy")

        buttonMinus = Button(frame1, text="-", height=3, width=5, command=subtract)
        buttonMinus.grid(row=row_index, column=col_index, sticky="nsew")
        buttonMinus.configure(width=7, height=3, font=("Verdana", 10, "bold"), fg="Navy")

        button1 = Button(frame1, text="1", height=3, width=5, command=lambda: buttonClick(1))
        button1.grid(row=row_index, column=col_index, sticky="nsew")
        button1.configure(width=7, height=3, font=("Verdana", 10, "bold"), fg="Navy")

        button2 = Button(frame1, text="2", height=3, width=5, command=lambda: buttonClick(2))
        button2.grid(row=row_index, column=col_index, sticky="nsew")
        button2.configure(width=7, height=3, font=("Verdana", 10, "bold"), fg="Navy")

        button3 = Button(frame1, text="3", height=3, width=5, command=lambda: buttonClick(3))
        button3.grid(row=row_index, column=col_index, sticky="nsew")
        button3.configure(width=7, height=3, font=("Verdana", 10, "bold"), fg="Navy")

        buttonAdd = Button(frame1, text="+", height=3, width=5, command=add)
        buttonAdd.grid(row=row_index, column=col_index, sticky="nsew")
        buttonAdd.configure(width=7, height=3, font=("Verdana", 10, "bold"), fg="Navy")
        
        buttonPlusMinus = Button(frame1, text="+/-", height=3, width=5, command=plusMinus)
        buttonPlusMinus.grid(row=row_index, column=col_index, sticky="nsew")
        buttonPlusMinus.configure(width=7, height=3, font=("Verdana", 10, "bold"), fg="Navy")

        buttonZero = Button(frame1, text="0", height=3, width=5, command=lambda: buttonClick(0))
        buttonZero.grid(row=row_index, column=col_index, sticky="nsew")
        buttonZero.configure(width=7, height=3, font=("Verdana", 10, "bold"), fg="Navy")

        buttonDecimal = Button(frame1, text=".", height=3, width=5, command=decimal)
        buttonDecimal.grid(row=row_index, column=col_index, sticky="nsew")
        buttonDecimal.configure(width=7, height=3, font=("Verdana", 10, "bold"), fg="Navy")

        buttonEquals = Button(frame1, text="=", height=3, width=5, command=equals)
        buttonEquals.grid(row=row_index, column=col_index, sticky="nsew")
        buttonEquals.configure(width=7, height=3, font=("Verdana", 10, "bold"), fg="Navy")

    frame2 = Frame(root, bg="lightgrey", bd=5)
    frame2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")

    historyButton = Button(frame2, text="Clear History", fg="Navy", bg="#80c1ff", command=clearhistory)
    historyButton.configure(font=("Verdana", 12, "bold"), fg="Navy")
    historyButton.place(x=5, y=40)

    memoryButton = Button(frame2, text="Memory", bg="#80c1ff", fg="navy", command=memory)
    memoryButton.configure(font=("Verdana", 12, "bold"), fg="Navy")
    memoryButton.place(x=135, y=40)

    self.result = Entry(frame2, width=24, borderwidth=3)
    self.result.configure(font=("Verdana", 14))
    self.result.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=5)

    root.mainloop()
```

Calculator()
...

Comment: I apologize for the formatting issue.

Comment: All of your `button` lines are indented one step too far.  They are part of the column for loop, and will be repeated 4 times

Comment: Tim, when I had the button lines one indent out, nothing got printed at all.  You're right though, a lot of times the right indentation can make a huge difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are placing all of your controls at `row=row_index, column=col_index`.  By the time that runs, `row_index` is 7 and `col_index` is 4.  You need to hard-code the locations for all of those buttons, as in `row_index=0, col_index=3`.  Then it will work.  I'm looking at it now:

[image]

Comment: Ok Tim.  Thank you!  I'll give that a shot!

Comment: Hi Tim, I changed the variables in the for loops to row and column from row_index / column index, and then hard-coded the values as you suggested.  It worked great!  Thank you!!

Comment: I had the grid of buttons displayed correctly on a FIXED window size, but what I REALLY wanted to do, was make it so the grid of buttons would automatically resize to a larger size when the window was maximized.  You helped me with that!!!